# Replace elements in a link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a link to add event to google calendar which is populated from a database, but the date is formatted yyyy-mm-dd, and the time hh:mm, and i cannot alter this, but google calendar will not accept.

Can anyone please help me use javascript and the 'replace' function to remove the'-' and ':' from the html please?

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?
action=TEMPLATE
&text=Tester12
&dates=2014-01-27T22:4000Z/2014-03-20T22:1500Z
&details=Oranges
&location=Newquay
&trp=false
&sprop=
&sprop=name:"
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

many thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: did you try to change  "2014-01-27T22:4000Z/2014-03-20T22:1500Z"  format?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything worth showing you, I am very much a learner. I just need to be able to remove the '-' and ':' from the link in order to get google calendar to accept the link, but I am just scratching my head in frustration. I cannot change the way the database result formats the date and time, so need to change it after the fact but before it goes to google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the href link from  tag and store it in a variable.

```
var linkStr = "http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Tester12&dates=2014-01-27T22:4000Z/2014-03-20T22:1500Z&details=Oranges&location=Newquay&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:";

var re = /&dates=.*?&/g;
var result = re.exec(linkStr);

if(result!=null){

             var replaceStr = result[0].replace(/[-|:]/g,'');
             var finalLink = linkStr.substr(0,result["index"]) + replaceStr + linkStr.substr(result["index"]+replaceStr.length);
             console.log(finalLink);
}else{
       alert('link invalid');
}
```

This will remove all the '-' and ':' from dates parameter string and will store that link in 'finalLink' var.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really value your imput. How do I apply that script to the link? I am very much in the learning stage, are you able to show me the whole thing? Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I have been on the sniff for the whole code solution, and witha bit of mix and match, came up with this, AND IT SEEMS TO WORK!!!!!! But please feel free to edit into perfection!

```html
<script>

var linkStr = "http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Example Event&dates=2018-12-16T10:3500Z/2018-12-16T12:0000Z&details=Trip to town&location=No mans land&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:";

var re = /&dates=.*?&/g;
var result = re.exec(linkStr);

if(result!=null){

             var replaceStr = result[0].replace(/[-|:]/g,'');
             var finalLink = linkStr.substr(0,result["index"]) + replaceStr + linkStr.substr(result["index"]+replaceStr.length);
             console.log(finalLink);
}else{
       alert('link invalid');
}

</script>
<a href="" class="finalLink">Add Event</a>
<script>
(function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a.finalLink"), function(link) {
    link.href = finalLink;
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Snippet doesn't work from this site but works fine on my PC, I assume that it's because you need to be logged in directly to google calendar for it to work! I have done this because I simply wanted a link on the back end of my website to add bookings to my calendar. I know there is a pay for service that does this, but could not justify the cost for purpose I will use it for.